# Touch screen Calibration doesn't work for Egalax Driver

Tags: drivers, xorg, touchscreen, xinput

I have installed egalax driver on Ubuntu Machine (14.04 LTS). Touch is working fine. But the calibration doesn't work.

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, it selects the eGalaxTouch Virtual device for Single for calibration and calibration screen opens but doesn't able to perform the calibration successfully.

The Xorg logs shows *divide by zero errors*

The machine is detected three (Multiple) eGalax devices.

Any ideas ideas to fix this problem when there are multiple devices detected.

```
xinput -list showing as below



root@50:~# xinput -list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer              id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ eGalaxTouch Virtual Device for Single   id=13    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ↳ eGalax Inc. USB TouchController         id=9     [slave  pointer  (2)]
|   ↳ eGalax Inc. USB TouchController Pen     id=8     [slave  pointer  (2)]|      
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                        id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard              id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ CHICONY USB Keyboard                     id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                             id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                             id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]



root@50:~# xinput -list-props 13
Device 'eGalaxTouch Virtual Device for Single':
        Device Enabled (114):   0

root@50:~# xinput -list-props 9
Device 'eGalax Inc. USB TouchController':
        Device Enabled (114):   0

root@50:~# xinput -list-props 8
Device 'eGalax Inc. USB TouchController Pen':
        Device Enabled (114):   0
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me some days till I found the problem, and I guess a lot of other people out there have the same problem.

I found the solution and the root cause why Libreelec + Kodi + eGalax touchscreen is not calibratable (axes are swapped and touchscreen calibration tool in Kodi (5-Point calibration) does not work).
The reason is that `ts_env.sh-sample` and the `ts_env.sh` derived from that has an error: it tries to match the device identifier, but at least in my case the command evtest shows two identical eGalax devices, only that one has the word "pen" behind it:

```
eGalax Inc. USB TouchController Pen
eGalax Inc. USB TouchController
```

The script detection stops on a full match, which unfortunately is the one with "Pen" behind it as it’s always listed first.
That is why "touchscreen" app in Kodi does not work and cursor x-axis and y-axis are inverted for the eGalax touchscreen and cannot be calibrated.

Solution: in `ts_env.sh-sample` the line

```
TSLIB_TSDEVICE=$(echo 999 | evtest 2>&1 >/dev/null | awk -F':' -v TS_NAME="$TOUCHSCREEN_NAME" '$0 ~ TS_NAME {print $1; exit}')
```

needs to be modified by adding a `$`-sign after `TOUCHSCREEN_NAME` like this:

```
TSLIB_TSDEVICE=$(echo 999 | evtest 2>&1 >/dev/null | awk -F':' -v TS_NAME="$TOUCHSCREEN_NAME$" '$0 ~ TS_NAME {print $1; exit}')
```

now the script only triggers the exact match (AND nothing behind, like "Pen").

For those who have the same problem and find this issue description I’ll guide you to the full solution here as well, as nowhere on the internet anyone seems to put references.

To get via ssh onto your libreelec/Kodi setup:
from a computer on the same network open a Linux console and type

```
ssh root@YOURIP
```

password will be asked, it is `libreelec`
Replace `YOURIP` with the actual IP address of the libreelec machine, you might log into your FRITZ!Box or Router to find it

Make sure ssh is enabled in Kodi settings
Also make sure "disable ssh password" is NOT (!!) checked.

as soon as you are logged in via ssh:

file location: `/storage/.kodi/userdata/addon_data/service.touchscreen/ts_env.sh-sample`

you can edit that file using nano:

```
nano /storage/.kodi/userdata/addon_data/service.touchscreen/ts_env.sh-sample
```

here you need to add the $-Sign as described above, then hit ctrl-o and enter to save and ctrl-x to leave nano

then,
following those instructions
https://forum.libreelec.tv/thread/15466-touchscreen-intel-x64-problem/#codeLine_41_com_woltlab_wbb_post_117185_8cecd7
everything works like a charm.

basically what the link describes is to copy the sample files to the right paths and to rename them (do that after the modification with the added `$`-sign that I described above):

```
cp /storage/.kodi/userdata/addon_data/service.touchscreen/ts_env.sh-sample /storage/.kodi/userdata/addon_data/service.touchscreen/ts_env.sh
cp /storage/.kodi/userdata/addon_data/service.touchscreen/ts.conf-generic /storage/.kodi/userdata/addon_data/service.touchscreen/ts.conf
cp /storage/.kodi/userdata/addon_data/service.touchscreen/ts.conf-generic /storage/.kodi/addons/service.touchscreen/ts.conf
cp /storage/.kodi/userdata/addon_data/service.touchscreen/ts_env.sh /storage/.kodi/addons/service.touchscreen/ts_env.sh
```

now you call

```
ts_env.sh
```

(without any path)

This is basically is the copy of the modified `ts_env.sh-sample` file

Then you type

```
reboot
```

After reboot your touchscreen app in Kodi will be able to do the 5-point calibration, as it now uses the right device.

It may be that some eGalax touchscreens don’t have this problem, but as it took me days to search all the forums I allowed myself to post the full solution here as well.

Comment: Excellent answer with nice findings but unfortunately not applicable to the actual question which is about desktop Ubuntu (and an already EoL release so better leave it alone). Librelec or anything else other than Ubuntu and official derivatives is off/topic here.